# Spring Boot ManyToMany Hibernate Persistance Performance

Tags: spring-boot, performance, hibernate, many-to-many, persistence

The question I have is probably a newbie one, however couldn't find the answer for that.

Why we use

```
        User usr = entityManager.getReference(User.class, userId);
        usr.getRoomsFavourites().add(entityManager.getReference(Room.class, roomId));
        entityManager.persist(usr);
```

Instead of directly insert into a relational table?

```
    @Query(value = "INSERT INTO user_room_favourites (user_id, room_id) VALUES (?1, ?2)", nativeQuery = true)
    void addFavoriteRoomByUserId(Long userId, Long roomId);
```

For the first option, we have a lot of overhead, even getReference only get the ID of Entity, it will go to the database, and in my case, it will make 3 large selects with a lot of joins before actually insert

For the second option, we only make the insertion

The only disadvantages I can see here are errors like user or room didn't exist or duplicate PK:

```
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [user_room_favourites_pkey];
```

But the exceptions can easily be handled.
Also, the migration for another database in the future can be more difficult because of Native Query.

I can not see any other disadvantage and I think for performance purposes the second way is much better.

Can someone explain this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi please add model class

Comment: Short answer: because we want to play with entities and not raw SQL statements. And also because JPA doesn't like it when we bypass the persistence context cache when making updates, leading to inconsistencies between the context and the actual state of the data source